# Insert SVG elements into HTML tag with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg, each

I have two SVG elements, my markup:

```
<svg>
  <circle r="260" fill="#1ABCb6" class="" id="svg_el_obj"></circle>
  <circle r="260" fill="#1ABCb6" class="" id="svg_el_obj"></circle>
</svg>
```

i need to insert them into `<g>` tag and in output watch this:

```
<svg>
  <g>
     <circle r="260" fill="#1ABCb6" class="" id="svg_el_obj"></circle>
  </g>
  <g>
     <circle r="260" fill="#1ABCb6" class="" id="svg_el_obj"></circle>
  </g>
</svg>
```

I try with jQuery but something is not right:

```
$('#svg_el_obj').each(function(){
   $(this).html('<g></g>');
}
```

or

```
$('#svg_el_obj').each(function(){
   $(this).append('<g></g>');
}
```

Much thx for help.

Answer (score 3):

You have multiple tags with the same id, id are to be unique. Try using a class instead and `wrap`

```
$('.svg_el_obj').wrap('<g>');
```

Comment: when i'm wrappig like this my svg elemnts disappears :(